# PHPUnit Selenium getting value out of HTML

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

Still pretty new to this and I'm struggling to get a value out of an HTML.
I'm using the PHPUnit selenium webdriver from Sebastian Bergmann

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">
<input type="text" id="function_function_name" name="function[function_name]" disabled="disabled" class="form-control input-sm" value="JOBSTUDENT">
</div>
```

*What I tried:*

```
$functie = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('function_function_name'))->getText();
```

**Result:** Echo's it blank.( Because there is no text, I don't know how to target the value )

Then I found about `getValueText` but when I tried using it:

```
$functie = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('function_function_name'))->getValueText();
```

**I got this result:**
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method RemoteWebElement::getValueText()

The output would be to echo the ' JOBSTUDENT '
What am I doing wrong/forgot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's getAttribute():

```
$functie = $this->webDriver
               ->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('function_function_name'))
               ->getAttribute('value');
```

I'm not sure if By::id() really targets id or the name. You could try this:

`->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('function[function_name]')`

Comment: You sir, are an angel. I'll accept it as answer in 9min , works like a charm thanks!